# Build a simple text square/rectangle using "Xs" and printf

Tags: c

I am trying to build a square/rectangle using "Xs" on a 1:1 scale with the length and width, but the logic seems to be not perfect

```
void draw (float x, float y) {
    int i, j;
    int length = (int)x + 0;
    int width = (int)y + 0;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < width; j++) {
            if (((i = 1) || (i = length)) && ((j = 1) || (j = width))) {
                printf("x");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the loop iterates endlessly printing x's everywhere. I'm expecting Xs to be printed out in either a square or rectangular shape (depending on the length or width).

Comment: What seems not to be perfect?

Comment: Please provide what output you are expecting and what are you getting for some `x` and `y`

Comment: In C, it is `==` that means equal sign.

Comment: Note that assignment is distinct from equality comparison in C. A good compiler would have warned you.

Comment: After that correction the loops will iterate one too few: to `width-1` and to `length-1`. So `i==length` and `j==width` will never be true.

Comment: The logic isn't perfect, the loop iterates endlessly. I'm expecting Xs to be printed out in either a square or rectangular shape (depending on the length or width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 flaws in your logic.

> you mix `=` (assignment) with `==` comparison.

This is why your loop never ends: you always reset `i` to `1` with your `if (((i = 1) || (i = length)) &...`

> you're not going far enough with your variables:

if `i < length`,  then you'll never have it reach `length` and print the bottom line of X's

> you can't draw a rectangle because your `&&` in the test `(((i = 1) || (i = length)) && ((j = 1) || (j = width)))` is too restrictive. It can't work if `width` different from `length`.

## You must learn the logic by yourself using tutorials:

Here such questions will be discarded by sometime-sad people. But as a welcome, here it is (you can replace `y` in the second case by `x`, but I thought it would help you understand):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void draw (float x, float y)
 {
   int i,j;
   int length = (int)x + 0;
   int width = (int)y + 0;
   for(i=1; i<=length; i++) {
       for(j=1;j<=width;j++) {
           if(((i==1)||(i==length))) {
               printf("x");
           } else {
             if (((j==1)||(j==width))) {
               printf("y");
             } else {
               printf(" ");
             }
           }
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
 }
```